# Importing to mixamo with weird results

Tags: rigging, mixamo

I bought an asset pack from unity of characters, exported them to FXB, imported them to blender, and after properly applying the textures, I passed it to mixamo. The problem is that I get a monstrosity in Mixamo, and I have no clue why.

[image: Blender]

This is in blender

[image: Mixamo]

This is in Mixamo

I also noticed that the mesh gets attached to Mixamo's camera (?)

How is it possible to properly export this character to use it in Mixamo?

I tried removing the skeleton in blender, exported, passed to mixamo, but mixamo's auto-rig is pretty bad with this character since the neck is not that long, so it also turns out to be a monstrosity, too.

After applying <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> for scale and rotation, I got this:

[image: Holy]

Comment: Did you apply the rotation and scale (Ctrl-A > Rotation & Scale in Object mode) to your model before exporting to Mixamo?

Comment: @JohnEason No, but I just did so, and the head just went away from the body. They're a bit far from it. Should I reposition them manually?

Comment: Oh my god. Please check the edit @JohnEason

Comment: Almost impossible to say what's going on to be honest as I've never used any Unity characters so don't know how they import into Blender. Since they're purchased characters you can't upload the Blend file for anyone here to see what's going on.

Comment: Are you sure all vertices are fully assigned to bones? Do you have a root bone, or any bone at the top of the whole bone hierarchy ?

Comment: Otherwise please upload your .blend on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and share the link here so that we can check it.

Comment: @L0Lock yes, will do so soon. Has been a busy day. I'll ping you both guys once its up there. Cheers!